# how can I hide an svg element with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, svg

How can I hide/show a element via visibility attribute  by its Id="test" given that code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ImageSvg from '../mysvg.svg';

export class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    public render() {
        return (<img src={ImageSvg } />);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope the code help you.

```
public render(){
  return (
    <div>  
        { this.state.show ? <img src={ ImageSvg } /> :'' }  
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I meant how to hide a certain element INSIDE the svg image?!

Comment: You can hide with css when you use react conditional rendering.React  either render your code or dont render.Dont hide or show an element.

Answer (score 0):

I will use props for that. Something like :

```
  render() {
  if(!this.props.show){
    return '';
  }
    return <img src={ImageSvg } />;
  }
```

Then you can use it like

```
<Test show="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional rendering:

```
    public render() {
        return {this.props.show && <img src={ImageSvg } />}
    }
```

In this case if the `show` property will be `true` then `<img />` will be rendered if no, then nothing will be rendered.

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Comment: I meant how to hide a certain element INSIDE the svg image?!

Answer (score 0):

If you but want the item to take up space when hidden so the layout doesn't shift, you could simply use inline-styles with visibility attribute:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ visibility: 'hidden'}}>
        Hi guys
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This way you would still have an existing element rendered and just control visibility via styling.